# A neat way of representing a matrix, where each column is a different matrix-vector product?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors

The background of my problem is quite complex, so I won't go through it here. It basically boils down to this:
Is there any neat way (matrix product etc.) to represent the $t\times r$ matrix
\begin{equation}
X=
\begin{bmatrix}
         & \\
        A_1\beta_1 & ... & A_r\beta_r\\
         & 
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
where each $A_i \in \mathbb{R}^{t\times n}$ and $\beta_i \in \mathbb{R}^n$? An optimal solution would involve all of the $\beta$-vectors in a single matrix.

Comment: what you by "neat" way to represent?

Comment: @pointguard0 anything "cleaner" than this, maybe some kind of matrix product?

Comment: see [Hadamard product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_product_(matrices))